# ImportError: No module named ezdxf

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

When I run python from SHELL the following error comes up:

```
    import ezdxf
ImportError: No module named ezdxf
```

I tried to use the same library with iPython and it works.
I updated the library and I reinstalled it.

How can I run the script successfully importing the function?

Additional info:

```
Requirement already satisfied: ezdxf in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from ezdxf)**strong text**
```

Comment: I'd suggest starting by looking in your `sys.path`. If it doesn't include `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, then we have a good idea of where to start.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` vs `/usr/lib/python2.7` is a bit suspicious, by the way -- have you installed your own Python interpreter not packaged by your OS vendor?

Comment: I am working on a shared computer on which I have sudo privileges limited only to my account. I installed python installing anaconda and I installed the library using pip.

What I cannot explain is that the library did not give me problems before the weekend. Nothing was changed since then and today it is throwing back this error.

Comment: You're going to have a very different PATH based on whether or not you're behind `sudo` or not. If `/usr/local/bin` isn't in your PATH, then your manually-installed Python won't be in use.

Comment: Reinstalled the library without `sudo` and it was placed in the anaconda directory.
Thank you @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps I am sure you will find the problem.

1. Find out the path ipython is using by:

   ```
   which ipython
   ```
2. open that file by:

   ```
   sudo vim *filename*
   ```

In my case it was `/usr/bin/ipython`

3. see the python path `ipython` is using by the first line of the program and write the same path in your script.

Comment: `which ipython` is actually less comprehensive/accurate/complete than `type ipython`; `which` is external to the shell, and thus has no way to know about shell functions or aliases, whereas `type` is built-in and can inspect the shell's own configuration and state.

Comment: `ipython is hashed (/home/pr13905/anaconda2/bin/ipython)`
Not sure what file you are suggesting to open.

Comment: Same file for your case : /home/pr13905/anaconda2/bin/ipython

Comment: On a more general situation this would be the right answer, but in my case  @CharlesDuffy suggestion hinted me to reinstall the library without `sudo`, and in this solved the issue.